# How to make CSS animation jump rather than slide

Tags: html, css

I have the following animation... http://jsfiddle.net/5vwjy/1/

**EDIT: Updated fiddle for all browsers... http://jsfiddle.net/5vwjy/2/**

Using the following CSS...

```
.box {
  display:block;
  width:240px;
  height:100px;
 background: red url("http://southwestphotobooths.co.uk/sites/all/themes/SWPB/images/check_availability.png") no-repeat;
  text-indent:-9999px;
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-animation-name: change;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(21);
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
}

@-webkit-keyframes change {

  0%    {top:0px;left:0px;background-position: 0px 0px;}
  5%    {top:0px;left:0px;background-position: -240px 0px;}
  10%   {top:0px;left:0px;background-position: -480px 0px;}
  15%   {top:0px;left:0px;background-position: -720px 0px;}
  20%   {top:0px;left:0px;background-position: -960px 0px;}
  25%   {top:0px;left:0px;background-position: -1200px 0px;}
  30%   {top:0px;left:0px;background-position: -1440px 0px;}
  35%   {top:0px;left:0px;background-position: -1680px 0px;}
  40%   {top:0px;left:0px;background-position: -1920px 0px;}
  45%   {top:0px;left:0px;background-position: -2160px 0px;}
  50%   {top:0px;left:0px;background-position: -2400px 0px;}
  55%   {top:0px;left:0px;background-position: -2640px 0px;}
  60%   {top:0px;left:0px;background-position: -2880px 0px;}
  65%   {top:0px;left:0px;background-position: -3120px 0px;}
  70%   {top:0px;left:0px;background-position: -3360px 0px;}
  75%   {top:0px;left:0px;background-position: -3600px 0px;}
  80%   {top:0px;left:0px;background-position: -3840px 0px;}
  85%   {top:0px;left:0px;background-position: -4080px 0px;}
  90%   {top:0px;left:0px;background-position: -4080px 0px;}
  95%   {top:0px;left:0px;background-position: -4080px 0px;}
  100%  {top:0px;left:0px;background-position: -4080px 0px;}

}
```

It works over 21 steps, using a really wide png to act as frames based on background position.

I can only get the animation to tween, rather than jump in stages.

How do I make it jump from frame to frame, rather than slide?

Comment: Why are you just targeting webkit browsers? Is that project specification? o_O  , I noticed because some users still use Firefox.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry, Im developing it in chrome, but I was going to add support for all browsers once the animation is right. I'll do it now.

Comment: I've just done it here...http://jsfiddle.net/5vwjy/2/

Comment: Well its relatively easy , just use steps. But honestly , I don't know about browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make changes to your css like:

```
-webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(1);
-moz-animation-timing-function: steps(1);
animation-timing-function: steps(1);
```

Tweak them with different values to get  desired animation , currently they show and stop at each of 21 frames. JSFiddle here : [CLICK](http://jsfiddle.net/5vwjy/4/)

Comment: Ah I see, I misunderstood that property. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5vwjy/5/)**

Use this property of css:

```
animation-timing-function: step-end;
```